# How do I back up just dbo and not the entire database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, backup, restore, dbo

I want to back up only the dbo's and not the entire database in MySQL. Backing up the entire database is easy. You simply right click your database, select "Tasks" -> "Backup" and you're done.

However, I do not want to back up the entire database. How do I just backup anything related to "dbo"?

Comment: Do you mean "How do I back up just the *schema* and not the data as well?" Hint: [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) has an option for this.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about MySql? Every single concept shown is specific to SQL Server.